# Apache log grep, awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to extract the email address from the apache log but having now luck with awk or a grep.

I've tired the below but completely lost

```
awk  -va="/folder/new/" -vb="_home" 'a {flag=1;next} b {flag=0} flag { print }'
```

Sample log line:

```
1.2.5.6 - - [01/Aug/2012:16:53:29 +0100] "GET /folder/new/user@example.com_home/some/rubbish/here/ "https://www.website.com/home.php" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.)"
```

Ideally I need to have a output like the below

```
user@exmaple.com using MSIE 7.0 on Windows NT 5.1
```

All help is grateful

Thanks

Comment: Did you try [scratchy](http://scratchy.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep "@" apache.log | sed -r 's,.*/folder/new/([^@]+@.*)_home.*"([^"]*)"$,\1 using \2,'
```

I am assuming "/folder/new/" and "_home" always appear like this.

This was tested with your line using GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the variability of your data, you could do this by specifying the relevant field separators:

```
awk -F '[/_()]' '{ print $6, $(NF-1) }' log
```

Output:

```
user@example.com compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in bash

```
regex='/folder/new(.*)_home.*"compatible; (.*); (.*);.*"'
[[ $logStr =~ $regex ]]
user="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
browser="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
os="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"

echo "$user using $browser on $os"
```

I'm not sure the regex is entirely correct; I may have made some assumptions about what fixed strings appear in the log message that aren't warranted. But hopefully, there's enough here to get you started if this approach interests you.